# linux IPv6 policy based routing fails

Tags: linux, ipv6, policy-routing

I have a VPN server that act as my IPv6 connection to the Internet. The setup us like this:

I have been assigned a /48 address pool, that I want to subnet to my VPN clients. For argument sake lets call the pool `2001:DB8:CAFE::/48`.

I have split that network up into the following parts:
`2001:DB8:CAFE::/64` is assigned to the actual VPN link between VPN server and each client.

  `2001:DB8:CAFE:100:/56` is assigned to the network behind Client 1

  `2001:DB8:CAFE:200:/56` is assigned to the network behind Client 2

This gives us this layout:

```
+--------------+  2001:470:xxxx:xxx::/64  +---------------+     /-> Client 1 network (2001:DB8:CAFE:100::/56)
|              + <-- Tunnelbroker link -> +               |    /
| The internet |                          | My VPN Server + <-*---> VPN link - network topology (2001:DB8:CAFE::/64)
|              + <- Native IPv6 link ---> +               |    \
+--------------+ 2a01:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx::/48 +---------------+     \-> Client 2 network (2001:DB8:CAFE:200::/56)
```

Want I want is that all traffic comming from `2001:DB8:CAFE::/48` is routed over my Tunnelbroker link - *and **only** that link*.

This leads me to the following script:

```
# Reset IPv6 routing table.
ip -6 rule flush

# Reset Tunnelbroker routing table (table name: "he-ipv6").
ip -6 route flush table he-ipv6

# Add routeable VPN subnets to Tunnelbroker routing table
ip -6 rule add from 2001:DB8:CAFE::/48 table he-ipv6

# Any traffic that originates from VPN has to be forwarded via Tunnelbroker routing table 
# using the tunnelbroker link (link name: he-ipv6).
ip -6 route add default via 2001:470:xxxx:xxx::1 dev he-ipv6 table he-ipv6

# Add default IPv6 rules again - since they gets deleted by the initial rule flush command.
ip -6 rule add priority 32766 from all table main
```

However: when I run the `ip -6 route add default ...`-command I get the following error back:

`RTNETLINK answers: No route to host`

The problem is that could ping `2001:470:xxxx:xxx::1` before I ran script, but not after.

What am I missing?

Comment: Just FYI: The IPv6 documentation address range is `2001:db8::/32`, not `db0`. (`db8` as in "debate"). :)

Comment: Oh right. :-) Anyway answer is going to be edited again. Apparently server does not agree wit

Comment: Grrr. Phone. Submit and go back placed next to each other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do'h! Order of commands ***matters***.

The reason the command `ip -6 route add default via 2001:470:xxxx:xxx::1 dev he-ipv6 table he-ipv6` didnt work was the route was defined in the `main` table.

But since the initial flush command removes the main table, you have to add it again **before** you do the `ip route default` command.

Correct script is therefore:

```
# Reset IPv6 routing table.
ip -6 rule flush

# Add default IPv6 rules again - since they gets deleted by the initial rule flush command.
ip -6 rule add priority 32766 from all table main

# Reset Tunnelbroker routing table (table name: "he-ipv6").
ip -6 route flush table he-ipv6

# Add routeable VPN subnets to Tunnelbroker routing table
ip -6 rule add from 2001:DB8:CAFE::/48 table he-ipv6

# Remember to add a rule that if no machine does not respond to a 
# packet address in my /48, then we should return unreachable. 
# Else the package will be forwarded by default out through the 
# Hurricane Electric connection.

#(From the Internet)
ip -6 route add unreachable 2001:DB8:CAFE::/48

#(From my /48 subnet)
ip -6 route add unreachable 2001:DB8:CAFE::/48 table he-ipv6

# Any traffic that originates from VPN has to be forwarded via Tunnelbroker routing table 
# using the tunnelbroker link (link name: he-ipv6).
ip -6 route add default via 2001:470:xxxx:xxx::1 dev he-ipv6 table he-ipv6
```

I will leave the question and answer in here, since I am problebly not the only one trying todo IPv6 routing based on source.

The most recent infomation I have found on the subject was from 2010.